# Using Isilon NFS for /var/lib/docker on RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, docker, nfs

RHEL: 7.8
Docker: 1.13.1

This server is shared among several teams, and I want to make docker available for testing or sandboxing for those that can't / won't install it on their laptop. Because it's shared, the image growth could get significant, I want to mount an Isilon NFS share as /var/lib/docker. I got it working using "vfs" as the storage driver, but I think it's the cause of the following error:

```
ERROR: for redis  Cannot create container for service redis: SELinux relabeling of <mount_point>/volumes/1185719ebf09771e9e9641f329c9c57f72792a942c283562f701ece914cca82a/_data is not allowed: "operation not supported"
```

I've seen a suggestion to try "chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t <mount_point>", but I get the same "operation not supported" error.

Has anyone else got this working? Am I going in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by uninstalling RHEL docker and installing docker 19.03.13 from docker.com. For those curious:

```
[root@oitleap01 ~]# docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 19.03.13
 Storage Driver: devicemapper
  Pool Name: docker-0:61-7297578891-pool
  Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
  Base Device Size: 10.74GB
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Udev Sync Supported: true
  Data file: /dev/loop0
  Metadata file: /dev/loop1
  Data loop file: /net/oitfile01/ifs/oitisilon/oit/Unix/ReplicatedData/UnixTeam/docker/oitleap01/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
  Metadata loop file: /net/oitfile01/ifs/oitisilon/oit/Unix/ReplicatedData/UnixTeam/docker/oitleap01/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
  Data Space Used: 11.73MB
  Data Space Total: 107.4GB
  Data Space Available: 107.4GB
  Metadata Space Used: 17.36MB
  Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
  Metadata Space Available: 2.13GB
  Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
  Deferred Removal Enabled: true
  Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
  Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
  Library Version: 1.02.164-RHEL7 (2019-08-27)
...
Docker Root Dir: <mount point>
...
WARNING: the devicemapper storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING: devicemapper: usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.
         Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
```